# Registering namespace with Zend Autoloader: Difference between including trailing "_" and not?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm wondering what the difference is between registering a namespace with Zend Autoloader as $autoloader->registerNamespace('My_'); and $autoloader->registerNamespace('My');.  I just didn't quite understand from the Zend Documentation, as I've tried it both ways and they both map fine to Project->Library->My.

Comment: I believe it is the class naming prefix. Thus `My_` should map to `My_Class` and `My` should map to `MyClass`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't change the mapping at all. Underscores are always mapped to directory separators. If a class to be loaded begins with the prefix, it will be autoloaded.

The difference between registering `My_` and `My` is that the latter will match `Mystery_Machine` while `My_` will not. Include the trailing underscore so that only classes in your `My` package will match and not any unrelated classes that happen to start with a word beginning with `My`.

We include it even though it's unlikely someone will have a class starting with `HGM` that isn't in our package.